# How do I access controller of an exported route in another route?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm using nested routes in typescript

I created a router  (review.route.ts) such as:

```
> review.route.ts
import { createReview } from "@controller...";

const reviewsRouter = Router() as Express;

reviewsRouter
    .route ('/reviews')
    .post(createReview);

export { reviewsRouter };
```

How can I access createReviews in another route?

I mean like; reviewsRouter.createReview (which does not work) in :

```
> items.route.ts

// Import reviewsRouter

itemsRouter.use("/:itemId/reviews", protectRoute, reviewsRouter.createReview);
```

I can't access createReview

Comment: Why do you want to use `reviewsRouter.createReview`? Can't you simply `import { createReview } from "@controller...";` again?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen the below should actually work:
```> items.route.ts

// Import reviewsRouter

itemsRouter.use("/:itemId/reviews", protectRoute, reviewsRouter);``` without having to do ```reviewsRouter.createReview``` but I got ```Cannot POST /items/itemidhere/reviews``` in postman.

Answer (score 0):

`itemsRouter.use("/:itemId/reviews", ...)` gobbles up the `/reviews` segment of the path, therefore `reviewsRouter.route('/reviews')` does not match any more. You can use a regular expression with a [lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions) to avoid that:

```js
itemsRouter.use(/\/(.*)(?=\/reviews)/, protectRoute, reviewsRouter);
```

The item ID will then be found in `req.params[0]` (instead of `req.params.itemId`).